# PDO connect to localhost (unknown mysql server host)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can connect to MySQL using `mysql_*` functions with the same credentials.

Is there any way to connect to a local MySQL database using PDO with a user that has `USAGE` privilege only? I don't have opportunity to set the rights to `ALL`, which I've read as a solution to a similar problem here in SO.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost,dbname=crmdb' (74)`

Comment: i would suggest you don't use PDO and you use the MySQLi interface in php it has objective support or `mysqli_*` support and i dont think it has the bug your seeing http://uk1.php.net/mysqli

Comment: How about no? I won't modify thousands of lines. With PDO I'm fetching results as objects of a custom class, where can you do this with MySQLi???

Comment: Thousands of line wow did you not build a class to manage that for you? and if that's the case i would say we need more information can you show us one of your calls and the SQL it builds before it sends it to the server, but i don't think you can get around this bug in PDO on php

Comment: `The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing account privileges.` from MySQL what are you trying to use with the User here as they can't do a lot

Comment: Hmm... so the only way if I call my boss to call the server administrator to grant ALL rights for the particular user, will it surely fix the problem?

Comment: @MartinBarker PDO is a lot better than mysqli for the simple reason of having named placeholders. There's no reason to switch here, this is not a PDO-specific issue.

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting, and if you can, post the line of code that's generating it.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost,dbname=crmdb' (74)` (generated by PDOException::getMessage())

Comment: @tadman i would never state that's a simple outright reason that it's better the only time i would recommend PDO is if you planning on your application work on different Database Server's name parameters are not a hard thing to replicate in a class str_replace dose it quite well, but as my other comments said after he said no we need to know what is happening to help.

And from the new comment the faceparlm followed by slap round the face  on my behalf is due, Semi-colon not comma!!! just proves you never tested or debugged your code coz it's blatantly in front of you is the error

Comment: Please don't off. I'm using PDO and I'm going to be using PDO. Accept that, and help me resolve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i was not meaning you i was meaning my self however i did state the answer it's a semi-colon not a comer in your connection string witch worries me that you have thousands of lines of code and you did not test/debug the first line of connecting to your DB server via PDO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 // PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password');
```

NOTE SEMI-COLON `;` NOT a COMMA `,`

Comment: Wow! I'm speechless. The thing is, that I've tested the script on a local webserver, which accepted `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306,dbname=test",'root','');` with a COMMA. Probably because there was no password set.

Comment: That's what i was meaning by we needed your code, just the error information i was able to denote that, however i stand by the i only use PDO when using multiple Database Types, as it's very big and complex for a simple type and yes the named parameters is a nice thing but it's really easy to do and you get a better implmentation you can have multiple uses of the same namespace,
`function prepareSQL($sql, $data){ foreach($data as $key => $val){ $sql = str_replace(":".$key, $val, 1); }  return $sql;}` oh and this supports object's or arrays of values :)

Comment: I would be worried about your test server there that's not right. and should not work as PDO builds a sort of ODBC connection from it all. E.G "mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=test;user=test" or if there is a password "mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=test;user=test;password=pass"

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the answer please as it has now been months since it was asked

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Have a nice day :)