# 2005 Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (11001)'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

Yeah,

I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (11001)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php.php on line 5

php.php contains the following:

```html
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/* Database Setting */
$db['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; //Mysql's Host
$db['port'] = '3306'; //Mysql's port
$db['user'] = "root"; //Mysql's user
$db['pass'] = 'pass'; //Mysql's password
$db['db'] = "db"; //Mysql's database

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db['host'].':'.$db['port'].';dbname='.$db['db'].'', $db['user'], $db['pass']);
```

I found some other posts but those were with the same error but then with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` its really weird, can you guys please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your mysql server is not running. Did you tried to restart XAMPP? Did you checked it's control panel with mysql status?

Comment: Yes I did @Mcload everything is running, and I can just normally access localhost/phpmyadmin (web panel).

Comment: I'm asking to reopen this post, the reason why it's not working because you specify the port number using this syntax `mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;...`, while it should be `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port:3306;...`,

Comment: That solution was an answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027089/765899
so the close because of duplicate is true.